# Ошибка в конструкции if/else if

Tags: c, if

Не получается вот такая простая проверка, не выводит содержимое внутри конструкции:

```
char answer[100];

printf("\nEnter option and press enter: \n");
fgets(answer, sizeof(answer), stdin);
answer[strcspn(answer, "\n")] = 0;

if (answer[100] == '1')
{

    const char* data = "Это список 1";

    printf(data);

}

else if (answer[100] == '2')
{

    const char* data = "Это список 2";

    printf(data);

}
```

Суть проста — пользователь вводит, к примеру, 1 и если это так, отдаём первое значение `data`; при вводе 2 — соответственно 2-е.

Comment: даже если предположить что чтрока 100 символов, последний символ будет answer[99]

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev, `if (answer[100] == 1)`, то, `printf(answer)` выведет `1`, но это если напечатать до конструкции. Внутри конструкции вообще ничего не выводится. Если (это нужно в результате), в конструкции оставить `data` и выводить за пределами, то функция не видит значения `data`. В сухом остатке, значения `data` не видно ни внутри конструкции, ни за её пределами. Цель — вытащить значение `data` в зависимости от условия и использовать в определённой функции.

Comment: Хрустальный шар подсказывает, что это была попытка сравнить введенную строку со строкой `1`, закончившаяся эпик фейлом из-за незнания про существование `strcmp`.

Comment: @user7860670, в самом деле, из-за незнания. Но я не могу сообразить, как её приспособить к моей задаче.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование `answer[100]` - ошибка, обращение к элементу за концом массива. Можно было бы записать условие как `answer[0] == '1'`, что означает "первый символ - цифра один". Но это плохо, если в меню будет хотя бы десять пунктов. Попробуйте так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char answer[100];

    printf("\nEnter option and press enter: ");
    fgets(answer, sizeof(answer), stdin);

    if (strcmp(answer, "1\n") == 0) {
        puts("Это список 1");
    } else if (strcmp(answer, "2\n") == 0) {
        puts("Это список 2");
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc temp.c
>
> $ ./a.out
>
> Enter option and press enter: 1
> Это список 1
>
> $ ./a.out
>
> Enter option and press enter: 2
> Это список 2
>
> $ ./a.out
>
> Enter option and press enter: 3
>
> $
> ```

**P.S.** `printf(data);` - не делайте так. Это работает пока в `data` не попадёт символ процента. А как попадёт, начнутся ошибки и неопределённое поведение. Если вы хотите именно `printf`, то `printf("%s", data);`. Это будет работать всегда.

Comment: Снова вы меня выручаете! :) Скажите, а если вот так, то, почему передаётся и значение `answer`?

`if (strcmp(answer, "1\n") == 0) {
  const char* data = "Это список всех номеров.";
  HPDF_Page_ShowText (page, data);
        
    } else if (strcmp(answer, "2\n") == 0) {
        const char* data = "Это список всех номеров одного рода.";
        HPDF_Page_ShowText (page, data);

    }`

Comment: @Max, не понял вопрос.

Comment: Ну вот если выводить `const char*`, то выводит вот так: `1(квадратик)Это список 1`, то есть, в вывод как-то попадает значение `answer`. :)

Comment: @Max, единожды испортив память можно получить любой результат. Задавайте новый вопрос.

Comment: @Max, зачем вы решаете задачу на C? С - головная боль, которую могут оправдать только очень специальные требования. Сделайте генератор PDF на Питоне. Там вы будете решать задачу, а не бороться с языком, который пока одерживает над вами верх.

Comment: вот в чём было дело, забыл затереть: `HPDF_Page_ShowText (page, answer);`. Видимо, пора спать :)